# powershell: invoke-webrequest on site that only uses password no username

Tags: powershell

i have had good luck with something like this against sites that ask for username and password

```
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $securePassword
$address = "https://somepage/login"
$body = (Invoke-WebRequest $address -Credential $credential).content
```

however i am now trying to get content from a page behind a login page that only uses a password and the above no long works.

i can't assign just a password or even a empty string for username to the $credential object.

i am hoping there is just another way to pull website content that is more flexible that i have not found yet.

i am currently using powershell v5

thanks for any help that can be provided

Comment: `behind a login page that only uses a password` what

Comment: I would inspect the post request from Chrome Dev tools to try to get an idea of what the body actually looks like

Comment: TheIncorrigible1: short answer, trying to pull logs from a device remotely and it's web interface is the only way to said logs which only requires a password for access.

Jacob: thanks for suggestion, i will give that a try next time i have a chance and reply back if that was fruitful.